# Error al minimizar una App en Swift

Tags: swift

Tengo un error que me aparece cuando minimizo mi app y la vuelvo a abrir.

> nw_read_request_report [C4] Receive failed with error "Software caused connection abort"

Solo eso me aparece, y es reciente. Además de que solo me aparece cuando ejecuto mi app en iPhone físico porque en el simulador no me da ese error, vi otras respuestas y dicen que estas corriendo diferentes versiones de Xcode, pero solo estoy corriendo 1, la última.

Alguna idea?
Afecta mucho ese error?

Comment: La app hace crash o deja de funcionar?

Comment: No, funciona todo good... no se finaliza solito ni nada.

Comment: Entonces es la conexión del dispositivo con Xcode, no es de preocuparse.

Comment: Uf!... muchas gracias.